# Join attribute lable in product collection

Tags: magento2, grid, product-collection, join

I'm creating one grid which will have to below columns like SKU,Name and Color (Attribute)

So to achieve this We've to join color data to collection for that I've added `_initSelect` to collection class.

```
public function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
         $select = $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity_varchar')], //2nd table name by which you want to join
            'main_table.entity_id= secondTable.entity_id', 
            ['value']
        );


        return $select;
    }
```

I stuck here how can I join attribute label based on its value and render that column to grid ?